# load multiple data from excel to sql SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I am working with SSIS and I need to load multiple files with the following (Yellos) format to SQL using SSIS

[image]

The problem as you can see is that the files has an horrible format only process / consume records if the column A is populated (e.g: ignoring rows# 14 - X ) and I need to insert the value in D1 into the Date column.

any suggestion?

Regards!

Comment: i provided a detailed solution, and i am waiting for your reply. Take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lets divide this problem into 3 Sub problems:*

1. *Get the date value from `D1`*
2. *Start Reading from Row number 4*
3. *Ignore all Rows where Column1 is NULL*

## Solution

***1. Get the date value from D1***

1. Create 2 SSIS variables, `@[User::FilePath]` *(of type string)* that contains the excel file path, `@[User::FileDate]` *(of type string)* that we will use it to store the date value
2. Add a script Task, choose the script language as *Visual Basic*
3. Select `@[User::FilePath]` as a *ReadOnly variable* and `@[User::FileDate]` as a *ReadWrite variable*
4. Open the Script Editor and use the following code to retrieve the Date Value and store it into `@[User::FileDate]`

*This will search for the sheet named `Refunds` and extract the date value from it and store this value into `@[User::FileDate]`*

```vb
    m_strExcelPath = Dts.Variables.Item("FilePath").Value.ToString

    Dim strSheetname As String = String.Empty
    Dim strDate as String = String.Empty

    m_strExcelConnectionString = Me.BuildConnectionString()

    Try


        Using OleDBCon As New OleDbConnection(m_strExcelConnectionString)

            If OleDBCon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                OleDBCon.Open()
            End If

            'Get all WorkSheets
            m_dtschemaTable = OleDBCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
                                                               New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})

            'Loop over work sheet to get the first one (the excel may contains temporary sheets or deleted ones

            For Each schRow As DataRow In m_dtschemaTable.Rows
                strSheetname = schRow("TABLE_NAME").ToString

                If Not strSheetname.EndsWith("_") AndAlso strSheetname.EndsWith("$") Then

                If Not strSheetname.Tolower.Contains("refunds") Then Continue For

                    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & strSheetname & "A1:D1]", OleDBCon)

                        Dim dtTable As New DataTable("Table1")


                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                        Using daGetDataFromSheet As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

                            daGetDataFromSheet.Fill(dtTable)

                            'Get Value from column 4 (3 because it is a zero-based index
                            strDate = dtTable.Rows(0).Item(3).ToString

                        End Using

                    End Using

                    'when the first correct sheet is found there is no need to check others
                    Exit For

                End If
            Next

            OleDBCon.Close()

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex)
    End Tr

    Dts.Variables.Item("FileDate").Value = strDate

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

5. In the DataFlow Task add a `Derived Column Transformation`, add a derived column with the following expression

   ```
   @[User::FileDate]
   ```

***2. Start Reading from Row Number 4***

*As we assumed that the Excel File Path is stored in `@[User::FilePath]`*

1. First open the `Excel Connection Manager` and uncheck the box `First row has column names`
2. In the DataFlow Task, double click on the excel source
3. Set the source to `SQL Command`
4. Use the following command: `SELECT * FROM [Refunds$A4:D]` , so it will start reading from the row number 4
5. Columns names will be as the following F1 ... F4 , in the excel source you can go to the Columns Tab and give alias to the columns names, so in the data flow task they will be showed with their aliases

***3. Ignore all Rows Where Column1 is NULL***

1. Add a conditional split after the Excel Source
2. Split the Flow based on the following expression

   ```
   ISNULL([F1]) == False
   ```

*If you didn't give an alias to `F1` otherwise use the alias*

Finally, remember that you must add a derived column *(as we said in the first sub-problem)* that contains the date value