# Unsupported data type on result set binding 0. from EXCEL file

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to get and store in a variable a value from the E1 column in an excel sheet with an execute SQL task like this:

[image: Excel File]

[image]

However I am getting the error:

> Unsupported data type on result set binding 0.

[image]

I set up the variable as String.

any suggestion?

Comment: since you have a scrip task, why don't you just try to fetch that value using a different method in code, and by pass the execute sql task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a normal select statement, example `SELECT * From blabla`, it doesn't return a Single value *(Single row may be used when using aggregate functions)*.

So you have to Select `Full Result Set` and mapp the result to a Variable of type `System.Object`.

After that add a script task, select the variable in the *ReadOnly Variables*, then in the script task, create a variable of type `IEnumerable` and assign to it the value of the package variable:

```vb
Dim dt = Dts.Variables.Item("User::Result").Value

'Dt(0)(0) will contains the value
```

Or you can achieve this using a `Script Task` instead of `Execute SQL Task`, just check my answer here:

- [load multiple data from excel to sql SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517548/load-multiple-data-from-excel-to-sql-ssis)