# SSIS loading Excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2016

This is my first time using SSIS, I'm getting this error.

Using: 
VS 2015, Excel 2010

> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8
>   Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [1]]: Opening a rowset for "'R0270 Cases$'" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

The first 7 rows in the excel file are headers information.  Row 8 has the column labels and data starts at 9.

*Excel Source Editor:*

Data access mode: Table or View

Excel Sheet drop-down, it errors out for the first 30 seconds then it populates with the sheet name.

Any clue what's happening and how can I skip the first 7 rows.  I have 100+ excel files and same thing happens on 8 different files.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Error possible solutions

1. You have to add `IMEX=1;` to your excel connection string, to helps excel to identify the data types correctly
2. Set the `DelayValidation` property of the `OLE DB Source` adapter to `True`.
3. Try removing spaces from sheet and excel file name

## Reading from row 8

***Assuming that you have 4 columns***

1. In the DataFlow Task, double click on the excel source Set the source to SQL Command
2. Use the following command: `SELECT * FROM [R0270 Cases$A8:D]` , so it will start reading from the row number 8 *(`D` means the column number 4 in excel)*

**References**

- [load multiple data from excel to sql SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517548/load-multiple-data-from-excel-to-sql-ssis/47519820#47519820)
- [Importing excel files having variable headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437513/importing-excel-files-having-variable-headers/47491497#47491497)

Comment: That Works!   Thanks